# Perl non-greedy Regex

Tags: regex, perl, class, html

So I finally got my boss to approve the use of perl for this purpose as opposed to sed.

Here's the basic quandry.

I have lines like this:

```
<div class="SectionText">Sometext</div><div class="SectionText">Some more text</div>
```

It's terribly messy, but I didn't write it. Either way, there are a goodly number of pages like this and they need to be changed to this format:

```
<p>Sometext</p><p>Some more text</p>
```

Obviously this needs to be non-greedy. Now here's the line I've come up with to help with this:

```
perl -nle "s/(.*)<div class=\"SectionText\">(.*?)<\/div>(.*)/\1<p>\2<\/p>\3/ig; print $1" "somefile.html" > otherfile.html
```

However, this does nothing and all of the SectionText tags still remain.

Comment: You say it needs to be non-greedy and yet put `.*` in the beginning, in the middle and at the end of the regex. Also, are you sure you don't want to use an actual HTML parser for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be aware that regular expressions are far from ideal for processing HTML. The proper way is to use a parser and manipulate the DOM, but you can get away with regexes for simple and well-behaved situations. Just be aware further down the line that this is a weak point in your design and may cause unexpected problems.

There is no need to capture and restore text outside the area to be edited. Simply replace the `<div>` element with a `<p>` element with the same content. There is also no need to escape double quotes or slashes as long as you choose different delimiters.

It is also wrong to use `\1`, `\2` etc. in the replacement string. `$1`, `$2` etc. belong here, and you would have been warned of this if you had used `-w` on the command line.

This should work for you

```
perl -pe 's|<div class="SectionText">(.*?)</div>|<p>$1</p>|ig' somefile.html > otherfile.html
```

Answer (score 4):

See [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://p3rl.org/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder)[::XPath](http://p3rl.org/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder%3a%3aXPath), and [HTML::Element](http://p3rl.org/HTML%3a%3aElement) for output methods.

```
my $t = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath
    ->new_from_content('<div class="SectionText">Sometext</div><div class="SectionText">Some more text</div>');
for ($t->findnodes('//div[@class="SectionText"]')) {
    $_->tag('p');
    $_->attr(class => undef);
}
```

To make it 100% correct, the `class` attribute value should be split on white-space, the class name `SectionText` removed, and then the attribute value reassembled. I think in your case you can get away with just deleting the `class` attribute as in the code above.